# rails 4 jquery only finds "body" element and nothing inside of it

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, selector

I am trying to use jQuery to hide a div, but the problem is none of my elements inside of body can be found. Even when I tried this code I get only the border around the body element

```
$('*').css("border","1px solid red")
```

Here is my source file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.msrinvestments.com/favicon1.ico"/>
        <title>MSR Investments</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
        <link data-turbonlinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/all/home.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/all/idx_maps.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/all/idx_types.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/all/indices.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/all/type_maps.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />

        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />

        <meta name="copyright" content="© 2013 MSR Investments" />
         <style></style>
    </head>

    <body >
        <div id="content" >
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="/"><img alt="Logo" src="/assets/logo.png" title="MSR Investments" /></a>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <img alt="Shadeimg9" src="/assets/shadeimg9.png" />
                <a href="/">HOME</a>
                <a href="/idx_types">SELECT AN INDEX</a>
                <a href="/indices">INDEX PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a href="">ABOUT INDICES</a>

                <a href="contact/contact.html">CONTACT</a>      
            </nav>

            <div id="main">
                <div id="backpic">
    <div id="pitch">
        <p>Find an investable index that suits your needs.</p> 
        <a class="button" href="/idx_types">Get Started</a>
    </div>
</div>
            </div>
            <div id="clear"></div>
            <div id="footer">
                <a href="mailto: info@msrinvestments.com"> asdf </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The previous border setting code is the only thing in the js files. They are all in the correct location in the "all" subfolder. I am only seeing the red border around the body element. When I try selecting other elements by id or class nothing happens. I've even tried completely emptying my css files and still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your scripts are loading in the `<head>` section.  That means that they are parsed and run BEFORE any of the HTML in the `<body>` section has been parsed and thus nothing will appear to be in the `<body>` yet.  You can either wait for the document to load before executing your scripts with code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put your jQuery or javascript code here that can operate on all 
    //     DOM elements present in the HTML of the page
});
```

Or, you can move your `<script>` tags to be right before the `</body>` tag so that everything before that will already be in the DOM when your scripts run.

P.S.  I rather doubt you actually want a red border around every single element in the page.  Hopefully that was just for testing purposes.  You may also want to consider using CSS rules in a stylesheet rather than applying styles with JS.

Comment: Thanks this worked. You are right, I was using the borders for testing. I have a button that I'm hiding if the browser has javascript enabled

Answer (score 0):

try call all elements with javascript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```